# Publish two plans related to each other

Tags: java, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I want to publish two plans that are related to each other. But this doesn't work as Bamboo throws an error because the related plan doesn' exist yet.

- PlanParent has a child dependency to PlanChild.
- PlanChild has an Artifact download task of artifacts from PlanParent.

```java
bambooServer.publish(planParent); // fails because planChild doesn't exist
bambooServer.publish(planChild);

// ---

bambooServer.publish(planChild); // fails because planParent doesn't exist
bambooServer.publish(planParent);
```

How to publish those two plans?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no better way than doing it in two steps.

1. Publishing the plans without the child plan dependencies
2. Publish the plans again including the child plan dependencies.

This worked for me.