# Bamboo specs create plans with circular dependency

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I am trying to specify multiple plans in bamboo specs (8.1.3) but those happen to have circular dependency:
Plan A (Unit tests) when finished - emits artifacts and triggers Plan B
Plan B (Sonar scanner) requires artifacts from Plan A

So in specs: A references B (child) and B references A (artifacts).

Everything is fine as long as those plans already exists but I would like to be able to define specs for a new project and then I get errors that referenced plan doesn't exist.
If I ever need to migrate entire specs there would be a lot of changes to first disable references and then enable them again so I would like to avoid that.

Is there any way for bamboo to first create plans and only then configure them? Maybe it is already supported in newer specs version? (I couldn't find any mention and cannot test it on my instance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Publish two plans related to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571304/publish-two-plans-related-to-each-other)

Comment: Hi @Alex this is exactly how I did this (comment out references, publish, uncomment references, publish), but I wondered if there is a clean way to do that. We have many projects that follow the same configuration so the way I implemented specs requires to remove references from ALL my plans and then add them again when adding a new similar app and that causes all our projects (10+) to have specs reloaded and references removed for a short period of time. This happens to be just a few lines of code to comment out but it affects many projects.

Comment: No easy way. If I were you, I'd add apply my specs manually (from localhost, not on Bamboo) in two stages. First create all plans without dependencies, then update each plan to add the necessary dependencies.